# How to Create a Loop for a Switch Statement That Repeats Until the User Types a Specific Word In C#

Tags: c#, while-loop, switch-statement, case, do-loops

I am trying to make a "coffee shop" where the console continues to ask the person what they want until they type finish. With the code I included, it asks what you want and then does the while loop once. I am very new to this so any help would be appreciated.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int totalCost = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Hi, what would you like to buy?");
        Console.WriteLine("Please type your choice; the menu is coffee, cookie, latte, muffin, tea, and brownie!");
        string food = Console.ReadLine();
        string v = "Thank you, that will cost $";

        do
        {
            food = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (food)
            {
                case "coffee":
                    Console.WriteLine(v + "4");
                    totalCost = totalCost + 4;
                    break;

                case "cookie":
                    Console.WriteLine(v + "2");
                    totalCost = totalCost + 2;
                    break;

                case "latte":
                    Console.WriteLine(v + "5");
                    totalCost = totalCost + 5;
                    break;

                case "muffin":
                    Console.Write(v + "3");
                    totalCost = totalCost + 3;
                    break;

                case "tea":
                    Console.WriteLine(v + "2");
                    totalCost = totalCost + 2;
                    break;

                case "brownie":
                    Console.WriteLine(v + "100");
                    totalCost = totalCost + 100;
                    break;

                case "finish":
                    Console.WriteLine("Your total is $" + totalCost + ". Thank you for your purchase - enjoy!");
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Hi, what would you like to buy?");
                    Console.WriteLine("Please type your choice; the menu is coffee, cookie, latte, muffin, tea, and brownie!");
                    break;
            }
            break; 
        }

        while (food != "finish");



        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: you have a `break` _after_ your switch statement. which lets your program `break` out of the surrounding loop. just remove it and you're set.

Comment: perhaps loop until a flag is set when the user enters the exit string, `while (!stop) {...}`

Comment: This would be an excellent time for you to learn to use your IDE's debugger. You would have quickly spotted it hitting that break statement. If you're using Visual Studio, take a look at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour).

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int totalCost = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Hi, what would you like to buy?");
        Console.WriteLine("Please type your choice; the menu is coffee, cookie, latte, muffin, tea, and brownie!");
        string food = "";
        string v = "Thank you, that will cost $";

        do
        {
            food = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (food)
            {
                case "coffee":
                    Console.WriteLine(v + "4");
                    totalCost = totalCost + 4;
                    break;

                case "cookie":
                    Console.WriteLine(v + "2");
                    totalCost = totalCost + 2;
                    break;

                case "latte":
                    Console.WriteLine(v + "5");
                    totalCost = totalCost + 5;
                    break;

                case "muffin":
                    Console.Write(v + "3");
                    totalCost = totalCost + 3;
                    break;

                case "tea":
                    Console.WriteLine(v + "2");
                    totalCost = totalCost + 2;
                    break;

                case "brownie":
                    Console.WriteLine(v + "100");
                    totalCost = totalCost + 100;
                    break;

                case "finish":
                    Console.WriteLine("Your total is $" + totalCost + ". Thank you for your purchase - enjoy!");
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Hi, what would you like to buy?");
                    Console.WriteLine("Please type your choice; the menu is coffee, cookie, latte, muffin, tea, and brownie!");
                    break;
            }
        }
        while (food != "finish");
        Console.Read();
    }
```

This code works as you expect